# iOS fullscreen animating with opengl es

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, drawing, fullscreen

Sorry for my poor English.

I created a iPad full-screen size 1024*768*4 bytes bitmap buffer in memory as off-screen buffer, and 2 threads, one of them update the buffer and call performSelector setNeedsDisplay on other thread, the another thread paint the whole buffer on screen in each drawRect cycle.

but this way is too slow. so I want improve the performance by changing it to the OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation.

My thought is to create a fullscreen texture, use CADisplayLink to fire a drawView selector every 1/60 second to update the texture by memory buffer and draw the texture on the screen. but i am new to opengl-es, I know how to initialize a simple EAGLLayer, create a texture from data, but I dont know how to draw the texture on the view, could any one give a sample?

Comment: "Give me code" type questions aren't really supported here.

Comment: create a OpenGL ES project from Xcode template and it will set everything up. or check out Cocos2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 is too much for just rendering the texture. OpenGL ES 1.1 is enough. Using shaders doesn't mean that it would be faster. To create full screen texture use two triangles with coords from -1.0 to 1.0 and apply texture.